# Spark Cassandra : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT

Tags: apache-spark

Can some help me convert the data from Cassandra row to be converted to Vector using Java

The code snippet where its failing is as below.

I am reading data from Cassandra table and trying to create a RandomForestClassifier model as below.

```
    JavaRDD<VibrationData1> vibrationReadRdd = CassandraJavaUtil
            .javaFunctions(sc)
            .cassandraTable("vibration_ks", "vibration_data_feature",
                    CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(VibrationData1.class))
            .select("classifier", "features");

    System.out.println("vibrationRdd.count()   --------- "
            + vibrationReadRdd.count());

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

    DataFrame data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vibrationReadRdd,
            VibrationData1.class);

    StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
            .setInputCol("classifier").setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
            .fit(data);
    // Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
    // Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as
    // continuous.
    VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
            .setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
            .setMaxCategories(4).fit(data);
```

The error is observed at line

```
VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new  VectorIndexer().setInputCol("features"). setOutputCol("indexedFeatures").setMaxCategories(4).fit(data);
```

The error message below

17/01/18 13:15:49 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: countByValue at StringIndexer.scala:86, took 3.331207 s
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce but was actually StringType.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer.transformSchema(VectorIndexer.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer.fit(VectorIndexer.scala:112)
        at com.edge.database.test.VibrationDBUtil.createSchema(VibrationDBUtil.java:161)
        at com.edge.database.test.VibrationDBUtil.run(VibrationDBUtil.java:95)
        at com.edge.database.test.VibrationDBUtil.main(VibrationDBUtil.java:217)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

The cassandra table is as below

cqlsh:vibration_ks> select * from vibration_data_feature;

uid | classifier | features

-----+------------+-----------------------------------------

15 |          0 | 10:0.0092 11:0.0093 20:0.0094 21:0.0095

17 |          1 | 10:0.192 11:0.3093 20:0.8094 21:0.9095

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you got solution for this?....i am also getting the same error